# [UITableViewCell _didChangeToFirstResponder:]: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: uitableview, ios7

I added textfield to tableview cell contentview.when i'm editing any textfield and i scrolled the tableview to bottom and  dismiss the keyboard Then app crashed ,because of this reason [UITableViewCell _didChangeToFirstResponder:]: message sent to deallocated instance

Comment: getting same error ..any Solution?

Comment: Same issue. Does not cause crash in iOS6

Comment: Show your textFieldShouldReturn method implementation.

Comment: -(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
       return YES;
}

Comment: is your issue resolved, if so, pls suggest the way.

Answer (score 6):

Try to hide the keyboard while scrolling.

In **h** class
 Declare a textfield

```
  UITextField *selectedTextField;
```

In **m** class

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{   
selectedTextField = textField;
return  YES;
 }
```

I also had the same problem. The above solution fixed it.

All the best.

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

[selectedTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
i don't want to dismiss the keyboard when i scrolling the tableview

Comment: I fought this for a while trying to find ways to scroll freely with my UITableView and arbitrarily select cells with UITextFields. I was consistently able to produce a crash at various places in my code until I implemented this. For my purposes, it really does not make that much of a difference from a user experience standpoint, might even make it a little cleaner. Never had this issue in iOS6. Really crappy that Apple has implemented code that causes bugs in our apps like this...

Comment: @Warrior I am also facing the same issue, is there any other way rather than hiding keyboard on scroll, if so, please share.